# how to bold the first <p> tags in array

Tags: css, vue.js

i've try using ::first-line but it bold all my p tags in array , the result i would like to want is bold only first p tags which is "Hello"

[image]

```
 <div v-for="item in first" :key="item.id">
       <p class="cat_name" >{{item.name}}</p>
</div>

<style scoped>

.cat_name >>> p::first-line
{
    font-weight: bold;
}

</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Way 1- Use loop index

As you said if you only want to bold the first element then you can simply use the index of the loop and assign the bold class only to the first element.

### Working demo-

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      first: [
        {
          id: 1,
          name: "Hello"
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          name: "Bye"
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          name: "Nice to meet you"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.cat_name
{
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
<div v-for="(item,index) in first" :key="item.id" class="list">
   <p :class="{'cat_name': index == 0}" >{{item.name}}</p>
</div>
</div>
```

## Way 2- Use :first-child rule

`:first-child` CSS rule will also work **but remember "The `:first-child` CSS pseudo-class represents the first element among a group of sibling elements."** That means all `p` elements should look like this-

```
<p>Hello</p>
<p>Bye</p>
<p>Nice to meet you.</p>
```

But if resolve your current loop HTML, it will look like this-

```
<div>
  <p>Hello</p>
</div>
<div>
  <p>Bye</p>
</div>
<div>
  <p>Nice to meet you</p>
</div>
```

Where all `p` elements are wrapped inside an individual `div` element which makes them no longer siblings to each other and that's why the `:first-child` CSS rule will apply to all `p` elements because every `p` element is the first child of its parent (`div`) element.
So, if you want to go this way then loop directly on `p` elements.

### Working demo-

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      first: [
        {
          id: 1,
          name: "Hello"
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          name: "Bye"
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          name: "Nice to meet you"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.list p:first-child {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div class="list">
    <div>
      <p v-for="(item,index) in first" :key="item.id">{{item.name}}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

### Note-

If looping directly on `p` elements is not possible then **way 1** is recommended.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 <div v-for="item in first" :key="item.id" class="list">
   <p class="cat_name" >{{item.name}}</p>
 </div>

<style scoped>

.list p:first-child
{
    font-weight: bold;
}

</style>
```

Comment: I guess this won't work because every `.list` class has only one `p` element which means every p element is the first child of `.list` and all `p` will have the bold CSS.